# Computer shuts down after a few minutes

Tags: hard-drive, memory, ssd, windows-8.1, power-supply

So I spent all day yesterday trying to figure out what was wrong with my computer. The specs look something like this (before replacing the board):

1. Z77 MSI M Power
2. Samsung 840 Evo SSD
3. 16GiB Ram (2 Corsair, 2 Patriot)
4. Intel i5 2800 series
5. Corsair RM850 PSU
6. Nvidia 2GB (cannot remember series)
7. OS - Windows 8.1

The main problem I keep having is after a certain amount of time, say 10 minutes the computer just shuts down. Goes to the "Shutting Down" orange screen. The two most recent pieces of equipment I installed were the SSD and PSU. I tried everything from 1 stick of RAM, still the same problem.

I installed Windows 7 on one of my spare hard drives, same thing happened. I swapped out the 1155 i5 with an Intel Celeron 1155, same shut down screen. Next thought that came to mind was the motherboard. So I swapped the Z77 with a MSI ATX.

Figured that was my best bet, same shut down screen. So after that I decided to try another PSU and low and behold, the same problem. So far the only thing I have been able to keep running is a copy of Fedora 18 on a really old WD hard drive but if I go to the files portion and look at the drives it says in red letters something along the lines of "This drive will fail soon".

I've done everything I can think of including switching out SATA cables. I am thinking something may be shorting the system out. My question is what would be the next logical trouble shooting point? Maybe someone else has had a problem like this?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: Forgot to mention as of a few days ago the computer was running great for a long time. Also the CPU temp does not go above 35C. The PSU is never hot to the touch nor is there any of the "burnt psu" smell.

Edit 2: While these shutdowns were occurring I was getting the message in event viewer "The kernel has initiated a shutdown". Sometimes the computer would stay on for 30 minutes, sometimes 2 minutes.

Comment: Do you see anything [like this](http://www.sevenforums.com/bsod-help-support/135862-notebook-randomly-shutting-off-2.html) in event viewer on the times of the shutdowns? Please post the event details if you find anything.

Comment: The reason the Fedora copy keeps on running is that it probably doesn't support ACPI events (or ACPI is disabled) so the hardware can't tell it to shut down.

Comment: No nothing like that event. Only thing that remains the same is the "kernal initiated a shutdown".

Comment: How is the power button configured? Shutdown or suspend/sleep? If the button or its connection to motherboard is flaky, it could possibly cause something like this.

Comment: I don't know how "intelligently" modern PSUs communicate with motherboards, but I wonder if this could, somehow, be related to unstable mains current/voltage... Anyhow, you don't have a UPS between the computer and the wall socket, do you?

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried letting the system idle in safe mode? Does that induce a reboot in a similar timeframe?

Comment: Boot into the hardware diagnostics and run a quick scan, followed by a full scan (will take several hours) if nothing is found.  Hardware diagnostics are usually accessed via a key combo during POST.  Once accessed, run a short or basic scan, then a full scan if nothing is found (will take several hours).  This sounds like a hardware fault if temperatures aren't in excess of 80C, and could be anything from a failing hardware component, to improperly seated RAM, improperly seated ribbon cable or HDD connection, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would still suspect over temperature.  If it's a laptop be sure not to block the vents on the bottom, e.g. the laptop sitting on soft surfaces.  If it's a desktop/console type check again for ventilation ports.  Those systems can be opened and cleaned using a compressed air can.  Perhaps a fan is malfunctioning or has a loose electrical connection.

Comment: Not a laptop. All fans properly operating. A through cleaning was my first step with a can of with.

Comment: And you put adequate thermal paste on the CPU when you swapped it out? @JoeKasavage

Comment: After the machine shutdowns start again and immediately get the BIOS, in it the health monitor and temperature in it. Please include this step and the value of temp. in the question. Also, it your thermal paste fresh enough? It is recommended to use new one, or less than 1 year old.

Comment: New paste. Temp never exceeds 40C after shutdown. Nothing is hot to the touch. That was my first thought.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the facts available, but what surprises me is that the shutdown screen is **orange**: Isn't it blue normally?

Actually the Windows Event log should contain details *why* the system was shut down.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (automatic shutdown after x minutes) once on a Microsoft domain controller. There was a problem with an expired license.

I dont have a windows system to test it actually, but you could try to check the license status via powershell:

```
Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct -Filter "Name like 'Windows%'" | 
where { $_.PartialProductKey } | select Description, LicenseStatus
```

It should be the following output (LicenseStatus == 1):

```
Description                                 LicenseStatus
-----------                                 -------------
Windows(R) Operating System, OEM_DM channel             1
```

Code taken from here: [How can I check if Windows is activated from the command prompt or powershell?](https://superuser.com/questions/1422368/how-can-i-check-if-windows-is-activated-from-the-command-prompt-or-powershell)