# How can I check if Windows is activated from the command prompt or powershell?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, windows-activation

If I want to check whether Windows is activated, but I can't be bothered to dive into the menu system or am on a version of Windows without Desktop Experience (such as Server Core), how can I check the activation status using only the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016/2019, to display the activation status using the command prompt (or powershell) open your preferred command line tool and enter the following command

```
slmgr /xpr
```

a dialog is shown indicating the operating system's activation status. If the operating system is not yet activated, the dialog will indicate it is in 'Notification mode'

[image: Command Prompt with open dialog indicating Windows is in Notification Mode.]

If Windows is succesfully activated, the dialog will indicate is is either 'Permanently Activated' as shown below, or if using a time-limited volume license activation the time the activation is due to expire will be shown.

[image: Command Prompt with open dialog indicating Windows is permantently activated.]

On older versions of Windows (such as Windows 7) the message dialogs will be similar but may have slightly differing text.

This method could also be useful to check the activation status during the out-of-box experience (OOBE) wizard by using Shift + F10 to launch a command prompt, before completing the wizard.

Comment: This answer does not work on systems without a GUI, which was an explicit part of the question. If you're running Server Core or are connecting remotely to a headless system, slmgr will return no results or appear to hang. This does work fine for most desktop users, however.

Answer (score 17):

A purely PowerShell solution would be:

```
Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct -Filter "Name like 'Windows%'" | 
where { $_.PartialProductKey } | select Description, LicenseStatus
```

This will give you an output like this:

```
Description                                 LicenseStatus
-----------                                 -------------
Windows(R) Operating System, OEM_DM channel             1
```

if LicenseStatus is 1, it means that the system is permanently activated.

Good thing about this is, that you can easily check RemoteMachines, by specifying the `-ComputerName` Parameter.

```
Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct -Filter "Name like 'Windows%'" -ComputerName RemoteComp | 
where { $_.PartialProductKey } | select Description, LicenseStatus
```

Though I gotta say that `slmgr /xpr` is faster and also clearer.

Comment: Are the different numbers documented somewhere?

Comment: Or `Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct -Filter "Name like 'Windows%' and partialproductkey <> null"`

Comment: Is there a way to get the expiration date?

Comment: This will save you 14 seconds.  `Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct -Filter "partialproductkey is not null" | ? name -like windows*`

Answer (score 3):

- To avoid the popup and
- store the windows version/activation status in a variable
- use `cscript` to run `slmgr.vbs` and wrap it in a batch file
- parse output with a `for /f` loop

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\04\07\SU_1422368.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "WinVerAct="

For /f "tokens=*" %%W in ('
    cscript /Nologo "C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs" /xpr
') Do Set "WinVerAct=!WinVerAct! %%W"
if Not defined WinVerAct ( 
    Echo:No response from slmgr.vbs
    Exit /B 1
)
Echo Windows Version Activation Status:
Echo:"%WinVerAct:~1%"
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\04\07\SU_1422368.cmd
Windows Version Activation Status:
"Windows(R), Professional edition: Der Computer ist dauerhaft aktiviert."
```

A single line PowerShell script wrapping slmgr.vbs:

```
$WinVerAct = (cscript /Nologo "C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs" /xpr) -join ''
```

Comment: and (as a little cherry on top) `Invoke-Command { (cscript /Nologo "C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs" /xpr) -join '' } -ComputerName xy` to check remote machines in PowerShell

Answer (score 3):

You can also do

```
SELECT LicenseStatus FROM SoftwareLicensingProduct
```

as a WMI query, where values are:

```
0=Unlicensed
1=Licensed
2=OOBGrace
3=OOTGrace
4=NonGenuineGrace
5=Notification
6=ExtendedGrace
```